# Cannot open Team Project resource in Azure portal after I have transfered subscription

Tags: azure, azure-devops, subscription, azureportal

I have transferred my Azure Subscription from personal Microsoft account to company account.

Now, when I log in to azure portal using company account, I see my team project resources (now called DevOps project). When I try to open it, it never loads:

[image: screenshot]

I'm also unable to fix my Azure Resource Manader Service Endpoint in VSTS, where I still log in using personal account

EDIT: 
I see certificate error in browser's log:

> SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x800c0019, Security certificate required to access this resource is invalid.

When I acccept the certificate I get:

> https://tfsprodweu2.cloudapp.net/signalr/negotiate?Authorization=Bearer%20e...
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://azuretfsextension.hosting.portal.azure.net'
>   is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code
>   404.

Comment: Did you accept the transferring email of your company account? And you can also refer transfer subcription ownship document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-subscription-transfer.

Comment: I did. In fact, all other resources works. This is bug in azure portal, see my edit

Comment: And just reminder: make sure you accept in the email link before it's expired.

Comment: I believe this is a bug. where can I report it? And btw, how do I verify that I've accepted the tranfering email?

Comment: You can report to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/forums/ or https://twitter.com/Azure.